# Automate javascript prompt using watin

Tags: c#, javascript, watin

I am automating a Javascript prompt by Watin. The prompt is displayed on button click.

I am using

```
button.click(); //the button click action

using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, alertDialogHandler))
                    {
                       alertDialogHandler.WaitUntilExists();
                       alertDialogHandler.OKButton.Click();
                       ie.WaitForComplete();
                    }
```

to handle the prompt. My problem is after the click, the control does not go to the next line where i have used `alertDialogHandler.WaitUntilExists();`

I have to manually handle the prompt. Is there a way to automate the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of button.click(), use button.ClickNoWait() and check.

Comment: @sham- using ClickNoWait() did solve the problem that control was not moving ahead. but it does not execute alertDialogHandler.OKButton.Click();

Comment: It would be useful if you can post the complete code related to Dialog Handler. Because I am not sure of 'alertDialogHandler'?
Thanks,
Sham_

Comment: WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.ReturnDialogHandlerIe9 myHandler = new ReturnDialogHandlerIe9();
                    ie.AddDialogHandler(myHandler);

Comment: @Adwait: Try below code
`ReturnDialogHandlerIe9 myHandler = new ReturnDialogHandlerIe9();
 ie.AddDialogHandler(myHandler);
 // Click element with no wait.
 button.ClickNoWait();
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
 // Wait until pop-up appears and click ok and remove handler.
 myHandler.WaitUntilExists();
 myHandler.OKButton.Click();
 ie.RemoveDialogHandler(myHandler);
 ie.WaitForComplete();`  
I have hard coded for 2 secs, you can modifiy it as per your need after re-running your test.

Comment: Not working
It gives an Watin exception 'Dialog not available within 30 seconds.' at WaitUntilExists();
If I remove WaitUntilExists(), it gives me a nullreference exception at myhandler.OKButton.Click();

Comment: @Adwat: Are you sure is it a JavaScript prompt? Can you please post the complete code.

Comment: it surely is a javascript prompt. For some reasons I cannot put up the code here. the button is actually an image which contains the attribute onclick() which corresponds to the same irritating javascript prompt, which asks me to enter a value and then press ok.

Comment: Can you post the complete HTML of that button (Image).

Comment: This is the span I click which results in that pop up
<span id="some id">
<span style="white-space: normal;">Sign Out</span>
</span>

Comment: I was successful in catching the pop up in Alertdialoghandler. I could also print the message in the pop up a message box, but 
alertdialog.OkButton.Click(); does not work. It does not click the ok button

Comment: If you are able to catch the dialog, then it should be possible to trigger action on it. Another solution is, once pop up is opened, if the default button is OK selected, then try to press enter, else use side arrow key press and then press enter.